# Read data from a JSON that is inside a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been trying for a while to access the value of a field that is inside a JSON, which is inside a normal dataframe, that is, the dataframe has a string field and its value is a JSON, I want to access a field of it and capture its value.

I leave an example screenshot:

[image]

I have tried a few ways, where the base is as follows:

```
collet_df = df_spark.collect()
for row in collet_df:
    new = row(JSON_COLUMN["id"]) 
    #new = str(row(["JSON_COLUMN"]["id"]))
    #new = str(row([JSON_COLUMN]["id"]))
    
    print(new)
```

Comment: Use `from_json` SQL function. Don't collect the dataframe

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need Collet() because I need to iterate through the records to make a POST of each one of them, will FROM_JSON still work for me?

Comment: what is your end objective and expected output? you can parse the json with `from_json()` and create new columns using its result.

Comment: You can iterate over rows of a dataframe and make HTTP calls on each row without collecting everything to your local machine (therefore defeating the purpose of using Spark as a distributed framework)